# How do I grant access to shared folder for local SYSTEM account in domain network

Tags: network-share

I have application that have to access shared network folder. Application runs under SYSTEM account so I have to grant SERVER-NAME\SYSTEM account access. When I try to input "SEVER-NAME\SYSTEM" into "Share Permissions" window - window tells me that I enter wrong account

Both servers are in domain

How can I grant access to SERVER-NAME\SYSTEM account?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that your machines are on a domain, processes running as the `SYSTEM` account will access the network using the computer account.

When adding the account to the share permissions, ensure that you have 'Computers' selected in the Object types and specify `SERVER-NAME` as the user name.

Comment: Try <domain>\<computername>$ in the object name box.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that with the computer name and it did not work. The only thing that worked is to add "write" permissions to the "SYSTEM" account(not qualified, just type "SYSTEM"). I think you have to select in Object types "Built-in security principals" to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to AD Users & Computers and find you server under the computers container. Then right click and then right click "Add to a Group".
I also struggled with this for about 15 minutes but that was what worked for me!