# Why process running as Local System accessing a UNC share being seen as NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, windows-service, unc, local-system

I have a Windows Service running as Local System on SERVER_X which is attempting to access a script on a UNC share hosted on SERVER_Y.

Per the links below, I've granted the computer account of SERVER_X access to the UNC on SERVER_Y.

[How to grant network access to LocalSystem account?](https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account)

[How do I grant access to shared folder for local SYSTEM account in domain network](https://serverfault.com/questions/411765/how-do-i-grant-access-to-shared-folder-for-local-system-account-in-domain-networ)

But, the Windows Service is unable to access the file (access denied errors).

```
dir \\SERVER_X\share
Access is denied.
```

In the Security Event log (on SERVER_Y) I see that SERVER_X is trying to access the UNC share as NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.  I would think that I should see the computer account (i.e. DOMAIN\SERVER_X) in the Security Event log.

[image: Security Event]

Both servers are Windows Server 2003 SE SP2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [Microsoft Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/05/14/troubleshooting-kerberos-authentication-problems-name-resolution-issues.aspx) which got me looking at using the server's hostname vs. CNAME.

Specifically, the below snippets:

> If you answered DNS name resolution you would be correct. **If name
>   resolution is not working properly in the environment it will cause
>   the application requesting a Kerberos ticket to actually request a
>   Service ticket for the wrong service principal name**. So if you
>   remember the remote file server I am attempting to connect to
>   “ltwre-chd-mem1.chd.litwareinc.com”, however the DNS Server found a
>   record for “ltwre-chd-mem1.litware.com”. Since we found the remote
>   file server in the “litwareinc.com” domain the Kerberos client
>   requests a service ticket for “cifs/ltwre-chd-mem1.litwareinc.com” as
>   noted in the Kerberos ticket request, and the KDC responds with
>   KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN.

And...

> Actually, there are several different ways to “fix” the problem:
>
> a. Find out why DNS is resolving the machine name incorrectly.
>
> i. **Is there a HOST or CNAME record for this name?**
>
> ii. Did you configure the DNS Zone for WINS lookup?

And...

> **If you find that fixing the DNS problem is not possible, then the next
>   best solution would be to make the application use the FQDN of the
>   server.** Keep in mind that the application vendor would need to be
>   involved to use this fix.

**Note:** When on a Windows Server 2008 host I could execute the dir command using the CNAME successfully.

**SOLUTION 1:**

Use hostname instead of CNAME.

I verified that if from a Windows Server 2003 host I accessed the UNC share with the hostname (i.e. `\\HOSTNAME\share`) instead of the CNAME (i.e. `\\CNAME\share`), the access would work fine.

*Example - WORKED:*

```
dir \\HOSTNAME\share
```

*Example - DID NOT WORK:*

```
dir \\CNAME\share
Access is denied.
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Set a SPN (service principal name) for the CNAME.

```
setspn -a HOST/CNAME SERVER
```

After doing this the `dir \\CNAME\share` worked.

Also see [How to Configure Windows Machine to Allow File Sharing with DNS Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/23823/how-to-configure-windows-machine-to-allow-file-sharing-with-dns-alias) for more information.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters DWORD:DisableStrictNameChecking = 1 can help you, but is it the answer of your question you posted ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Thank you. I checked the server hosting the UNC and it already had that registry key set with 1.  Per this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308), I think your registry suggestion plus the SPN is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you access a UNC share without previously established network credentials, you end up as anonymous.  The *local* SYSTEM account obviously isn't a valid network login.

Comment: Microsoft has [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677973%28VS.85%29.aspx) stating this: _When a service runs under the LocalSystem account on a computer that is a domain member, the service has whatever network access is granted to the computer account, or to any groups of which the computer account is a member._

Comment: Yes, but @psusi is right, as the fallback is anonymous user, why? because the SMB share is validated in user-space, this is not a NFS's share. You want the computer account to login, you will have to enter the computeraccount in the 'local admin' group of that remote computer.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation is correct. Please see the links in my OP. I've granted Full Control Security access to the UNC share to the computer account DOMAIN\SERVER_X$ like mentioned in the links. Giving this Security access to the computer account will give Local System on SERVER_X access to the UNC. I'm successfully doing this with other servers. I'm just looking for ideas why this is not working for a specific server.

Comment: @Jesse check your local gpo on the remote server if you allowed anonymous enumeration of share

Answer (score 0):

Run the service under an user account to bypass the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option.